# jQuery on click not picking up content changed by AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

The age old question again!

I have a button to load more posts via ajax, which works fine. The button has some data attributes which tell the AJAX function what category (`data-id`) to get posts from.

```
<a href="#" class="button js-load-more" data-page="1" data-id="4" data-taxonomy="sectors" data-posttype="products">Load More Products</a>
```

I have a filter (a `select` element), which lets the user change the `data-id` attribute of the button above.

When you use the filter dropdown to change the `data-id`, the buttons `data-id` is updated in the `DOM`, but the data sent via AJAX doesn't pick up the new `id`, instead it sends the old `id`, meaning it gets the wrong category.

#### Load more button

```
$(document).on('click', '.js-load-more', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var button = $(this);
    var offset = $('.product-box').length+1;
    var termID = button.data('id'); // NOTE: this seems to not pickup the new ID if it's been changed
    var taxonomy = button.data('taxonomy');
    var postType = button.data('posttype');
    var ajaxDump = $('.ajax-dump');

    button.html('Loading...');

    $.ajax({
        url: loadMoreProducts.ajax_url,
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            action: 'load_more_products',
            offset: offset,
            termID: termID,
            taxonomy: taxonomy, 
            postType: postType,
        }, 
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {

            var products = result.posts;
            var count = result.count;

            ajaxDump.append(products);
            moreProductsCallback();

            if( count < 12 ) {
                $('.js-load-more').hide();
            }
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });

    function moreProductsCallback() {

        ajaxDump.find('.page.hide').fadeIn(500, function() {

            $('.page').removeClass('hide');
            $.fn.matchHeight._maintainScroll = true;
            $.fn.matchHeight._update();
            button.html('Load More Products'); 

        });
    }

});
```

#### Filter dropdown

```
$('.js-filter-sector').on('change', function() {

    var ajaxDump = $('.ajax-dump');
    var button = $('.js-load-more');
    var termID = $(this).val();
    var taxonomy = button.attr('data-taxonomy');
    var postType = button.attr('data-postType'); 

    $.ajax({
        url: loadMoreProducts.ajax_url,
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            action: 'load_more_products',
            offset: 0,
            termID: termID,
            taxonomy: taxonomy, 
            postType: postType,
        }, 
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {

            var products = result.posts;
            var count = result.count;

            $('.js-load-more').show();
            ajaxDump.empty();
            ajaxDump.append(products);
            filterSectorCallback();

            if( count < 12 ) {
                $('.js-load-more').hide();
            }
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });

    function filterSectorCallback() {
        ajaxDump.find('.page.hide').fadeIn(500, function() {

            button.attr('data-id', termID); // NOTE: this works, updates the ID on the element
            $(this).removeClass('hide');
            button.html('Load More Products'); 

            $.fn.matchHeight._maintainScroll = true;
            $.fn.matchHeight._update();

        });
    }


});
```

One weird thing to note is that if I use the filter first, without loading more posts, it does fetch the right posts. It seems to only be an issue if you run the filter after you've already fetched more posts.

Could this be a cacheing issue with the AJAX maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're using `data()` as the getter (which is good) but `attr()` as the setter. This means that the value is set in a different location from where you are attempting to read it.

To fix this use `data()` to both get *and* set the value:

```
// in click handler of .js-load-more
var termID = button.data('id')

// in change handler of .js-filter-sector
button.data('id', termID);
```

I would also suggest you change the other uses of `attr('data-*')` too:

```
var taxonomy = button.data('taxonomy');
var postType = button.data('postType');
```

This is because `data()` should always be used when dealing with `data` attributes, unless you explicitly need the attribute to be read from the DOM (such as for a CSS selector).

Comment: Ah, worked a charm! Thanks! Thanks for the clarification also on .data and .attr, I didn't realise there was a difference between the two.

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Comment: I seem to have an offset/paging issue now, but I'll have a nose through the code first to see if I can spot the issue. The filter ajax seems to be offsetting the posts by a few pages, instead of `0` as set in the filter AJAX call, strange!